# How to replace 2 values at one replace call

Tags: javascript

So i am wondering how i can replace two or more at once with single replace call.

I haven't tried anything so far, as i don't have a clue how i can do that.

```js
let links = {
   _init: "https://%s.website.com/get/%s",
}
```

So as you can see here i have a link with 2x %s which i want to replace.
I am thinking about something like this:

**links._init.replace('%s', 'name', 'query')**

obviously it won't work. So i am wondering if there is other way of doing it.
I know that languages like python, c# etc have similar feature.

Comment: Why not make your own replace function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use a replacer function, and an array that you `shift()` from:

```js
let links = {
   _init: "https://%s.website.com/get/%s"
};
const replaceWith = ['name', 'query'];
const replaced = links._init.replace(
  /%s/g,
  () => replaceWith.shift()
);
console.log(replaced);
```

If you don't want to mutate the existing array, you can also use a counter that gets incremented on every iteration:

```js
let links = {
   _init: "https://%s.website.com/get/%s"
};
const replaceWith = ['name', 'query'];
let i = 0;
const replaced = links._init.replace(
  /%s/g,
  () => replaceWith[i++]
);
console.log(replaced);
```

Comment: O! Thank you so much :)